# IntelliJ code style only break on whitespace

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to create a code style in IntelliJ to keep formatting consistent. I want to ensure the right margin is not exceeded, but when I reformat and IntelliJ tries to enforce that, it often results in some quite strange looking lines.

For example, it often likes to break the line in the middle of a string resulting in something like

```
public static final String SOME_CONSTANT_STRING = "A long string that is cut" +
        + " off in the middle.";
```

What I would like instead, is for IntelliJ to only break the line at whitespace so the line would instead look like

```
public static final String SOME_CONSTANT_STRING =
        "A long string that is cut off in the middle";
```

Is this behavior possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces` ...

- `Assignment statement > Wrap if long`
- `Assignment statement > Align when multiline`

Here's a screenshot showing the configuration:

[image]

Here's a screenshot showing the outcome after applying this formatter to the declaration of a very long string constant:

[image]